# Does Linear Change of Variables in Integration Distort the Result?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, multiple-integral

I am not 100% about this claim, so I would like a proof or a counterexample.

First, let $\mathbb{R}^n$ have standard basis $e_1,\dots, e_n$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ have coordinates $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. Suppose $Q$ is a multiple of $e_1$ and let $\mu$ be the measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with density $(1+|x-Q|^2)^{-(n+1)/2}$. Let $S$ be a simplex with vertices $s_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $s_1,\dots, s_n\in Q^\perp$.

**Claim**: If $T$ is an linear transformation fixing $Q^\perp$, then

$$0=\int_S (x-Q)d\mu=\int_{TS} (x-Q)d\mu$$

implies $TS=S$.

**Progress**: Since $T$ is linear and fixes $e_2,\dots, e_d$, there must be some $\tau\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $$T(x)=x+x_1\tau$$ The premise becomes

$$\int_S (x-Q)(1+|x-Q|^2)^{-(n+1)/2}dx=\int_{TS} (x-Q)(1+|x-Q|^2)^{-(n+1)/2}dx$$

Now, enact a change of variables to get the regions to match,

$$\int_S (x-Q)(1+|x-Q|^2)^{-(n+1)/2}dx=\int_{S} (x+x_1\tau-Q)(1+|x+x_1\tau-Q|^2)^{-(n+1)/2}dx$$

I expect since $T$ moves all the points in $S$ in the direction of $\tau$ that the right hand integral in the claim will also move in the direction of $\tau$ (specifically a positive inner product with $\tau$).

We might suppose $\tau\neq 0$ and take inner product with $\tau$ on both sides to maybe get inequality?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: $\int_S (x-Q)d\mu = 0$ alone implies $s_0 \in Q^\perp$. Since $T$ fixes $Q^\perp$, it makes no change to the simplex.

Comment: $\int_S (x-Q)d\mu=0$ is a paraphrase of $Q=(1/\mu(S))\int_S xd\mu$. So, $s_0$ is free to roam.